# How to improve the Annoying Orange effect?

Tags: node-editor, video-sequence-editor, masking

I'm working on a project that is using the annoying orange technique.
It works fine but the mouth is surrounded by that shadow. 
I know it due to the feather of the mask I'm using.

Do you guys have an idea how I can make the transition smoother so it will blend in better?

[image]

Comment: Alpha looks good? Is that the premuliplied version already? Colors are matching? Are you using blenders compositor? Did you already tried *Set Alpha* node? A lot of questions, I know :)

Comment: need more info and or a file